# Mask path to a file

Tags: php, wordpress

We plan to add an auto update function to our premium wordpress theme. Now you have to set the url to your update file so wordpress can download it. Example:

```
$update['package'] = 'http://example.com/theme.zip';
```

Do you think there is a chance to mask that url? I don't want that everyone can just share the url. I tried something like [this](http://www.tutorialchip.com/php-download-file-script/) but unfortunately the auto update only works with a direct path to the url. (or maybe iam doing something wrong)

Maybe there is a chance to use the same technique as the webfont services?

Any ideas would be great!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

A download script is the way to go. There shouldn't be a difference if you use a direct link to the file or one to a downloader script. You can add some info from the $_SERVER array to identify your downloader - if your customers are bound to an domain or something.

Comment: Hi Markus, do you have any tip or example for me?